# Argument passing by reference to a class in python (á la C++), to modify it with the class methods

Tags: python

In this case, I want that the program print "X = changed"

```
class Clase:
  def __init__(self,variable):
    self.var = variable
  def set_var(self):
    self.var = 'changed'

X = 'unchanged'
V = Clase(X)
V.set_var()

print "X = ",X
```

Comment: strings are unmutable ... and all mutable arguments are always pass by reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python `list` and `dict` types are global and are passed around by reference. So if you change the type of your variable `X` to one of those you will get the desired results.

[EDIT: Added use case that op needed]

```
class Clase:
  def __init__(self,variable):
    self.var = variable
  def set_var(self):
    self.var.test = 'changed'

class ComplicatedClass():
    def __init__(self, test):
        self.test = test

X = ComplicatedClass('unchanged')
print('Before:', X.test)

V = Clase(X)
V.set_var()

print("After:",X.test)

>>> Before: unchanged
>>> After: changed
```

Comment: Everything is passed by reference, and I'm not sure what you're trying to say about being "global" but that's probably not true. If it is -- it's certainly not something specific to dicts and lists

Comment: I guess I was trying to say that these data types are mutable

Comment: Thanks! 
I have a doubt... my real objetive is to change a object that is not a string or list, is a complicate class  I did.

Do you know how I can create a "global class" ?

Answer (score 4):

All values are objects and are passed by reference in Python, and *assignment changes the reference.*

```
def myfunc(y):
     y = 13

x = 42       # x now points at the integer object, 42
myfunc(y)    # inside myfunc, y initially points to 42,
             # but myfunc changes its y to point to a
             # different object, 13
print(x)     # prints 42, since changing y inside myfunc
             # does not change any other variable
```

It's important to note here that there are no "simple types" as there are in other languages. In Python, integers are objects. Floats are objects. Bools are objects. And assignment is *always* changing a pointer to refer to a different object, whatever the type of that object.

Thus, it's not possible to "assign through" a reference and change someone else's variable. You can, however, simulate this by passing a mutable container (e.g. a list or a dictionary) and changing the contents of the container, as others have shown.

This kind of mutation of arguments through pointers is common in C/C++ and is generally used to work around the fact that a function can only have a single return value. Python will happily create tuples for you in the `return` statement and unpack them to multiple variables on the other side, making it easy to return multiple values, so this isn't an issue. Just return all the values you want to return. Here is a trivial example:

```
def myfunc(x, y, z):
    return x * 2, y + 5, z - 3
```

On the other side:

```
a, b, c = myFunc(4, 5, 6)
```

In practice, then, there is rarely any reason to need to do what you're trying to do in Python.

Comment: this is what I was trying to say ... worded much better :P

Comment: Thanks for your answer:
I have a list_of_points, and I want to define classes as polygon,curves, etc that only keep what points are connected. Every object polygon or curve can modify the list_of_points, and implicitily, affect to the other objects... for this reason I want to do that... maybe my approach is very non-pythonic

Comment: Hard to say without more information, but if you have a list of points, you can certainly modify its contents without running into any such limitation. It's easy even to entirely replace the list's *contents* with something totally different. You just can't substitute a *different* list object for it.

Answer (score 2):

strings are immutable so you could not change X in this way
... an alternative might be reassigning X in the global space... this obviously will fail in many many senarios (ie it is not a global)

```
class Clase:
  def __init__(self,variable):
    self.var = variable
  def set_var(self):
    globals()[self.var] = 'changed'

X = 'unchanged'
V = Clase('X')
V.set_var()

print "X = ",X
```

the other alternative is to use a mutable data type as suggested by Ashwin

or the best option is that this is probably not a good idea and you should likely not do it...

Comment: ` the best option is that this is probably not a good idea and you should likely not do it...` agreed :)

Comment: Or create a mutable wrapper around the string. It's super kludgey, but kind of works https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/03293e0c355c34d2657e